# Расположение элементов в layout

Tags: android, java

1)

[image: img]

вот на этой картинке стрелку нужно поместить в левый край, а остальные два элемента оставить по центру.

вот код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_back" />  

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pray_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/prayer_list"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

спасибо заранее.

2) это не такое важное.
как сделать кнопки как  в меню `es explorer`

[image: img2]

вот что по второму у меня получилось

[image: img3]

осталось только картинку с текстом как-то поместить в центр квадрата.
не знаю как это сделать. Текст и картинка итак в центре, но нужно чтоб и по высоте они были прижаты к центру

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_effect"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPray"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/content_paste"
            android:background="@drawable/white_effect"
            android:text="@string/prayer_requests" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDiary"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/content_edit"
            android:background="@drawable/white_effect"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/diary" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTips"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/action_help"
            android:background="@drawable/white_effect"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/prayer_tips" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOptions"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/device_access_alarms"
            android:background="@drawable/white_effect"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reminder" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCredits"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/action_about"
            android:background="@drawable/white_effect"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/credits" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonQuit"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/navigation_cancel"
            android:background="@drawable/white_effect"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/quit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

добавил вот такие свойства и все получилось

```
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="28dp"
    android:paddingTop="28dp"
```

Comment: как по мне не первое не второе. не важное :) или зачес ты это тут постишь?

Comment: что значит неважное? мне нужно imageview back поставить в левый край. я не знаю как это сделать. поэтому и запостил. это же вроде форум где задают вопросы и отвечают на них или как?

Comment: да, форум где задают вопросы, а не раздают задания ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первому пункту, примерно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_back" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pray_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prayer_list"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: абсолютно правильно. благодарю

Comment: ребята давайте будем чуть добрее и не будем минусовать вопросы(пускай и не самые умные, но в запарке отнимающие время которого всегда нет) формат форума так раз и предполагает вопрос - ответ, без левых расшаркиваний.   сори за офтоп )